# "The quartiles, whose importance is" - is the "whose" used correctly?

Tags: word-choice

the question is already standing above.
For those who are not familiar with the word "quartile":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile (it is a statistical parameter)
I am looking forward for your answers!
Kind Regards

Comment: Can you finish the sentence, please?

Comment: "The quartiles, whose importance has been laid out in chapter x, are y"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid ascribing a personality to a statistical quantity, I would rephrase the sentence to read,

> "The quartiles, the **importance of which** has been laid out in chapter x, are y."

For additional information on relative pronouns, see: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-relative.htm